# Where is the cause for the width-overflow?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, overflow

I've got a problem... I cannot localize the cause for the width-overflow...

Could anyone take a look at it?
http://sulayman.org/

I've already been watching out for reasons - but didn't find anything.

Thank you all!

Comment: Looks fine to me, I can't see any width overflow. FF 3.6 on Windows 7

Comment: I'm using Chrome 5.0.322.2 DEV... do you see a scroll-bar at the bottom? That might be the overflow...

Comment: Nope, tested in FF3.6, Chrome 4 and IE 8, I get a scrollbar at the bottom when I squeeze my window to about < 800 Pixels, not before.

Comment: I knew that before ;D

But I didn't get a rid of a solution, yet..

Anyhow - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

div with a `class="navigation clear"` has a property

```
margin: 0 0 25px 0;
```

The `25px` is causing this weird behaviour.

Comment: That is the problem. You have your style.css included twice which can make it hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

There is no width overflow with Firefox 3.6.

If you insist there is, insist back to your browser with a body {width: 100%; overflow: hidden;}